# Why does kendo-grid using Razor not have OData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid

I have a kendo-grid using remote binding to an old WCF service. I have made some new OData services and i puzzled that OData isn't a property when I switch.

Old code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "odata", // <-- This property exist
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "http://localhost:49168/MyDataService.svc/Products",
                        data: { $expand: "Department,Editorial"}                            
                    }
                },
```

New Code that does not work

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Product>()
    .Name("grid")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .OData() // <-- This property does not exist but I would think it should
        .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.Id))
                        .Read(read => read.Url("http://localhost:52706/odata/ProductsData"))
    )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summer 2015:

I guess this is not supported. I found it as a wish on the website.

http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-telerik-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/4388607-odata-support-for-kendo-ui-asp-net-mvc-server-wrap